# How do I insert two images and one text in the status bar in wxpython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

How do I insert two images in the status bar in wxpython in this format: 
*image1.jpg------image2.jpg---------project_name(some string)*

My code is something like this:

```
self.StatusBar = self.CreateStatusBar(3)
self.Set_Text_Value(self)
self.Centre()
self.Show(True)
self._init_coll_StatusBar_Fields(0)
self._init_coll_StatusBar_Fields1(1)

def Set_Text_Value(self, event):   #for reading a file containing project name
    fob = open(r'C:\3d-Model\bin\curr_proj.txt' , 'r')
    s = fob.read()
    a= s.split("\\")
    s1= a[3]
    self.StatusBar.SetStatusText('PROJECT:  '+ s1 , 2)

def _init_coll_StatusBar_Fields(self, parent):       #for inserting image1
    bmp1 = wx.Image('image1.jpg',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG).ConvertToBitmap()
    def scale_bitmap(bitmap, width, height):
        image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
        image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
        return result
    bmp1 = scale_bitmap(bmp1, 75, 25)
    bm1=wx.StaticBitmap(self.StatusBar , 0 , bmp1)
```

And similarly for inserting second image i have _init_coll_StatusBar_Fields1

The output shows only one image in the left- most corner of first status bar,the other being hidden under it if both have same dimensions.
How do i go about the code?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want that order in the layout of the frame?

Comment: Yes.
Basically I want to insert two images in the status bar and also one text..

Answer (score 0):

I believe by the default StatusBar class does not support the level of customization you're looking for. Try using [EnhancedStatusBar](http://wiki.wxpython.org/EnhancedStatusBar). It should have no problem doing what you want.